# Is a DSP required with a SIP trunk?

Tags: cisco, voice

Assuming a Cisco 3825 router, if the Cisco SCCP phones on the network are using G.711 µ-law and are traversing a CUCME system connected to a SIP trunk that supports G.711 µ-law, is a PVDM2 DSP card required since the codecs are the same? Does having a Unity Express module installed on the system require a DSP card?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be good without DSPs.  The major use of DSPs on a router is when you have to convert from a TDM trunk (FXO or T1/PRI) to an IP resource.  Since SIP is all IP-based, you shouldn't have to do any conversion.

Do be aware that any conference calling features will consume DSPs unless you have a hardware conference bridge.

Comment: I completely forgot about conference calling -- thanks!

Comment: transcoding is another common use for DSP's.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not transcoding is required.  If you are using a codec in-house that is incompatible with your SIP providers gateway then yes.  Otherwise, no.

Same with Unity Express voicemail.  If the voicemail is using the codec you run in-house, no transcoding required.  However if you are compressing voicemails (recording them in g.729, for example), then you will have to invoke the DSP to transcode.  Otherwise, users can't leave VM's.